# Elasticsearch search-ui with React

Tags: reactjs, elasticsearch, elasticui

I have a React site with aside and main content. I want to use [search-ui](https://github.com/elastic/search-ui) for searching on the site.

The search bar should be on the aside, and when the user searches for something, results should be displayed on the main content. Aside and main content are two separated react components.

In my aside, I'm configuring search-ui SearchBox like this

```
<SearchBox
    autocompleteResults={{
        titleField: "title",
        urlField: "url"
    }}
    autocompleteSuggestions={true}
    onSubmit={searchTerm => {
        navigate("/elastic-search?q=" + searchTerm);
    }}
    onSelectAutocomplete={(selection, {}, defaultOnSelectAutocomplete) => {
        if (selection.suggestion) {
            navigate("/elastic-search?q=" + selection.suggestion);
        } else {
            defaultOnSelectAutocomplete(selection);
        }
    }}
/>
```

So when the user searches something the app will redirect to a separate page named elastic-search and I'm passing the searchTerm in the URL through navigate method.

On MainContent I have results like this:

```
<Results titleField='title' urlField='url'/>
```

Now the question is how can I fetch searchTerm and display the results on main content. The structure of the app is like this:

```
<App>
   <SearchProvider config={config}>
      <Aside /> ---- Here I have <SearchBox>
      <MainContent /> ---- Here I have <Results>
   </SearchProvider>
</App>
```

When I search the app redirects to /elastic-search with searchTerm in URL, but the results are not displaying. If I refresh the page they are displayed. How can I notify Results or re-render the page, so I can show the searched results.

Answer (score 2):

Your **Results** seems to be missing some parameters and should look something like this:

```
<>
  <Results
    titleField="title"
    urlField=""
    view={SearchView}
    resultView={SearchResultView}
  />
</>
```

And your **SearchView** (Used to override the default **view** for this Component.) and **SearchResultView** (Used to override individual **Result views**.) components, should look something like this:

```
const SearchView = ({ children }) => {
   return <div>{children}</div>
};

const SearchResultView = ({ result: searchResult }) => {
  return <div>{searchResult.content}</div>
}
```

#### Additional suggestion

This is a working example in the Next.js app with `import { useRouter } from "next/router";` that needs to be replaced with your routing solution. In the **SearchBox** component:

```
export const SearchBoxComponent = () => {
 const router = useRouter();
 return (
  <>
  <SearchBox
    searchAsYouType={true}
    autocompleteResults={{
      titleField: "title",
      urlField: "",
      shouldTrackClickThrough: true,
      clickThroughTags: ["test"],
    }}
    autocompleteSuggestions={true}
    onSubmit={(searchTerm) => {
      const urlEncodedQuery = encodeURI(searchTerm).replace(/%20/g, "+");
      router.push(`/search?q=${urlEncodedQuery}`);
    }}
    ...
    </>
    )
    }
```

Comment: It's not working. It looks like SearchBox and Results are not connected. When the page redirects to the new search page, nothing happens...

Comment: Seems like the issue is in the routing. Are you using react-router-dom in your app? I have a working example in the Next.js app, that I can post as a reference, so you can adjust it for vanilla React.

Comment: Added additional suggestion with working example of SearchBox to the initial answer.

Comment: I am using Gatsby, and I'm routing with gatsby Routing